# How to get total record fields from mongodb by using $group?

Tags: mongodb

I wants to get records with all fields using $group in mongodb. 
i.e: SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY state,  equivalent query in mongodb.
Can any one help me.

Comment: I'm not entirely what you're trying to achieve with `SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY state`. You'd usually use aggregation in conjunction with `GROUP BY` statements, what results do you expect your SQL query to yield? Once we have that worked out, we can see whether there's a way for MongoDB to perform the same query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to return all object in group query. You can use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) operator to add fields into the array to return. The example code is shown in the below. You can add all the fields to the array using addToSet operator. It will return array as a response and you should get data from those array(s).

```
db.users.aggregate({$group : {_id : "$state", id : {$addToSet : "$_id"}, field1 : {$addToSet : "$field1"}}});
```

Comment: Thanks parvin. i am getting list of id's in a group by using your given code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce) instead:

```
db.runCommand({
  mapreduce: 'tests',
  map: function() {
    return emit(this.state, { docs: [this] });
  },
  reduce: function(key, vals) {
    var res = vals.pop();
    vals.forEach(function(val) {
      [].push.apply(res.docs, val.docs);
    });
    return res;
  },
  finalize: function(key, reducedValue) {
    return reducedValue.docs;
  },
  out: { inline: 1 }
})
```

I'm using `finalize` function in my example because `MapReduce` not supports arrays in `reducedValue`.

But, regardless of the method, you should try to avoid such queries in productions. They are fine for rare requests, like analytics, db migrations or daily scripting, but not for frequent ones.